# How to open new activity when ImageView is click in the fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Hi Im a newbie in android, can some help me implement a click on my ImageView to open new activity. I tried several codes but the app crashes on launch. Here is my code on fragments

Fragment1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selectone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fashion"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selecttwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/selectone"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lingerie"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titlelabel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/selectone"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Fashion"
        android:textColor="#fefefe"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titlelabel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/selecttwo"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Lingerie"
        android:textColor="#fefefe"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment1.java

```
package com.androidbegin.sidemenututorial;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

ImageView fashionImg;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //get the button view
    fashionImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.selectone);
    //set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
    fashionImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //Start new list activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CarouselActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: sure i can help you with that. what error do you get?

Comment: show us the stacktrace?

Comment: I cant see any error on the logcat but when i start to run the app it launches but crashes or stop. is there other way to implement an onclick listener to my ImageView, thanks

Comment: when it does crash there is a logcat-output of it.   if logcat doesnt show anything at all, just restart your IDE..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As shown below add code into onActivityCreated() instead of onCreate()

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // get the button view
    fashionImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.selectone);
    // set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
    fashionImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        // Start new list activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    CarouselActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your Fragment1 class like this :

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

ImageView fashionImg;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

     //get the button view
    fashionImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.selectone);
    return rootView;
}

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CarouselActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this by:

```
fashionImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.selectone);
```

to

```
fashionImg = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.selectone);
```

Comment: why is that? he needs reference to the view, not the activity.

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `android:onClick="onClick"` in the `ImageView` with something like `android:onClick="onClickTest"`. Then in the code write something like:

```
public void onClickTest(View v){

        //The MainActivity being the starting point
        Intent int = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                CarouselActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the listener in onCreateView. Refer Fragment lifecycle, the problem is onCreate is called before onCreateView so your fragment's view is not added to the parent container view by that time.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
//get the button view
    fashionImg = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectone);
    //set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
    fashionImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //Start new list activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CarouselActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });


    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, first place an ImageView like this

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Then place all other ImageView or images over this.
In your 'Fragment1' class use OnTouchListener.

```
image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Intent mainIntent =new Intent(Fragment1.this,CarouselActivity.class);
            stratActivity(mainIntent);
            return true;
        }
});
```